# How to add parameters to a sub-reports in a dashboard SSRS

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I have 5 SSRS 2010 reports, each of them has two parameters with default values.
I created a Dashboard and adding all those subreports to it. In a dashboard I have created exactly the same parameters, then in each subreport properties I added parameter. 
But when I preview report it doesnt display any data, or changing parameters wotn do anything. 
[image]

Whar am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set the subreport parameters' **VALUE** to the parameter in the main report.

[image]

As a side note, you may need to reselect the subreport if you can't see the parameters in the drop down menu.